# coalesce more than 1 column in sql server

Tags: sql-server, coalesce

I have the following query where I search 2 tables for the item price

```
select productSerial, productName

coalesce(

(select top 1 price
from productPrice pp
where pp.id = wi.id
order by pp.date),

(select top 1 price
from productPriceEast ppe
where ppe.id = wi.id
order by ppe.date)

) as baseprice

from warehouseItems wi
```

but now I want the description too, how to change the query to get more than 1 column?  I cannot change the query to this since the coalesce would fail.  I was thinking of select those queries in the coalesce into temp tables and do some sort of join instead of coalesce not sure if that is correct approach.

```
select top 1 price, productDescrip
from productPriceEast
where ppe.id = wi.id
order by ppe.date
```

Comment: @PaulWhite cant really do that proprietary data also I condensed the actual query to the example above it's way longer

Comment: See [mcve] but it is of course up to you. Just a suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need an `OUTER APPLY`

```
select
  wi.productSerial,
  wi.productName
  isnull(pp.price, ppe.price) as baseprice,
  isnull(pp.description, ppe.description) as description
from warehouseItems wi
outer apply (
    select top (1)
      pp.price,
      pp.description
    from productPrice pp
    where pp.id = wi.id
    order by pp.date
) pp
outer apply (
    select top (1)
      ppe.price,
      ppe.description
    from productPriceEast ppe
    where ppe.id = wi.id
    order by ppe.date
) ppe;
```

Comment: FWIW, you can reduce the number of `OUTER APPLY` subqueries to 1 or none even, with a `FULL JOIN` between `productPrice` and `productPriceEast` in a single subquery first. Though in my experiences, `FULL JOIN`s tend to be counterintuitive to performance. If OP provided more details and data, it would be helpful for testing.

Comment: True, although I tend to go for a `where firstApply.PK is null` clause in the second apply, which is more indicative of the intention when using `isnull` and can als be more performant as it can short-circuit the join.

Comment: never used outer apply before but I'm assuming I'm searching more than 2 tables would work just as well?  Just need to replace isnull with coalesce?

Comment: Yes, although I generally recommend nested `isnull` calls for performance reasons (because  `coalesce` compiles into a complex `case`)

Comment: hm ran into another problem so if pp.price is not null I'd want to use pp.description and same thing ppe.price needs to be with ppe.description.  Do I need some sort of switch in that case?  Otherwise this query is working well.  It looks like right now ppe.price can match with pp. description in the final table.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, it should just work using `isnull`. If the columns themselves are nullable then you probably need `where pp.price is not null and pp.description is not null` inside each `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

The [`COALESCE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function accepts more than two parameters. For example, the following is valid syntax:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Expression1, Expression2, Expression3, Expression4, Etc)
```

Not sure what you're actually stuck on?...if you could provide your table definitions, some sample data, and example expected output, it may make your goal more clear.

For example, you can concatenate two subqueries together in the same expression of the `COALESCE()` clause, if your goal is to show the `price` with the `productDescrip` together, like so:

```
SELECT 
    productSerial, 
    productName,
    COALESCE
    (
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 price
            FROM productPrice pp
            WHERE pp.id = wi.id
            ORDER BY pp.date
        ),   
        CONCAT
        (
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 price
                FROM productPriceEast ppe
                WHERE ppe.id = wi.id
                ORDER BY ppe.date
            ),
            ' ',
            (
                SELECT TOP 1 productDescrip
                FROM productPriceEast ppe
                WHERE ppe.id = wi.id
                ORDER BY ppe.date
            )
        )
    ) as baseprice
    FROM warehouseItems wi
```

Assuming your `ORDER BY ppe.date` clause is deterministic for a given `ppe.id`.

Or even simpler, `CONCAT()` the two fields inside the original subquery expression like so:

```
SELECT 
    productSerial, 
    productName,
    COALESCE
    (
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 price
            FROM productPrice pp
            WHERE pp.id = wi.id
            ORDER BY pp.date
        ),   
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 CONCAT(price, ' ', productDescrip) AS priceAndProductDescrip
            FROM productPriceEast ppe
            WHERE ppe.id = wi.id
            ORDER BY ppe.date
        )
    ) as baseprice
    FROM warehouseItems wi
```